# Problems with 360 Video in Unity Player

Tags: unity-game-engine, unity3d-2dtools, 360-video

I'm building a simple 360 video project and mostly got it to work. I've successfully imported the video and configured project so I can pan and 'look around' the environment when the Unity IDE is playing the video in Scene mode.

When I try to build the project or run it in Game mode, it looks as if I'm staring at a wall.

None of the articles on 360 video mention things about camera placement.

I've noticed a button labeled '2D' in the Scene view button bar that looks eerily similar to how the software renders the project in Game mode.

I feel like I'm missing a switch or a configuration somewhere.

Thanks for your assistance.

I tried setting a number of different build settings for Unity Player that didn't work.

I'm attaching screenshots of what I'm seeing.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZXrHX.jpg)

Here's the game view mode.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZRG9V.jpg)

Comment: if you look at your scene view the camera seems to indeed be stuck on facing directly on a wall ...

Answer (score 1):

There's an additional step that's not posted in most 360 vid tutorials.

Even though the scene view allows you to look around by placing a camera. The MainCamera needs to be coded in order to work.

The camera code here: http://mountainpath.ch/cmsimplexh/index.php?Unity-3D/Create-a-3D-model-viewer-with-Unity-3D

Got this thing to work as expected.